# HTML 5 JS Draggable Below Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with dragging an element below the viewport. When I try to drag the element below the viewport the page will not autoscroll. As you can see in the image I have provided I am trying to drag an element below. The only way I can scroll below the viewport to drop my element in Firefox is to use the mouse wheel.

If I left click and hold while dragging down on **this** Stack Overflow page the viewport autoscolls downward. This is how I need my web app to perform.

I'm not really sure where to start with this as it is a paid WordPress plugin called Learndash that not properly coded.

Can anyone point me to the correct solution to this problem?

Thanks.
[image: drag problem image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link to automatically scroll the window.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3460-automatically-scroll-the-window-when-the-user-approaches-the-viewport-edge-in-javascript.htm

Edit:

1. Add a margin below your div to allow space to insert
2. Or add the CSS properties height:500px and overflow-y:scroll in your div